# Visual Studio block commenting doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio

[image]

I select some lines and press ctrl+e+c but instead of commenting the lines, it comments exactly the part that I select. This wasn't how it used to work. How do I fix this?

Comment: The default comment keystroke is Crtl+K+C for the last 3 versions *at least*. There is no block comment command. Were you using a third-party addin perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

VS works on ctrl+k+c for Commenting.

Thanks